# Issue with a button in parent when jQuery UI Dialog cancel action is triggered

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a form with the following submit button:

```
<td valign="bottom" id="form-submitted">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart">
</td>
```

Upon click, I have :

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {   

    $("#form-submitted").html("<img src='../images/loader.gif'/> Saving, please wait...");
    ...
    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: dialogHeight,
                width: 650,
                modal: true,
                position: {
                    my: "center bottom",
                    at: "center"
                },  
                buttons: {
                    "Continue": addSold,
                    Cancel: function() {

                        $('#form-submitted').html('<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart">');

                        dialog.dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {

                    $("#s-total").html("<b>Total : 0</b>");

                }
         });  
    ...
});
```

If I click on cancel in the UI dialog, I see the btnSubmit in the form. However, the second click will not trigger the UI dialog.

How do I make sure the second click on btnSubmit also triggers the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions here that should be of use:  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1079849/Jquery-hits-only-once-in-dymanic-button-clicks